# Removed Slashes in WPF Extended Toolkit DatePicker

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I am using the WPF Extended Toolkit ([Extended Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/)) DatePicker and I am having trouble with my `/` being removed from my Dates, however `-` works without a hitch. Here is an image of what I mean;

[image]
[image]

As you can see the second example is working fine. Here is the code for those two respective `DatePickers`;

**DatePicker1**

```
<wpftk:DateTimePicker x:Name="createdPicker" AutoCloseCalendar="True" Margin="5" Format="Custom" FormatString="dd/MM/yyyy" FontSize="22" TextAlignment="Left"/>
```

**DatePicker2**

```
<wpftk:DateTimePicker x:Name="createdPicker" AutoCloseCalendar="True" Margin="5" Format="Custom" FormatString="dd-MM-yyyy" FontSize="22" TextAlignment="Left"/>
```

Predictably the only thing that I have changed is the `FormatString="dd/MM/yyyy"` to `FormatString="dd-MM-yyyy"`. How can I prevent the `/` from being removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the culture settings. Changing the default culture to (for example) invariant, fixes this issue:

```
var ci = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Name);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```